# Generate a dataframe with conditional combination of range of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, math

I am trying to calculate the following formula:

[image: Formula]

I wrote this to calulate this:

```py
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["h","i","j","k"])
x1=10
y1=8
m=7
P_List = []
m_range = np.arange(0,m+1)

for m in m_range:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["h","i","j","k"])
        h_range = np.arange(0,x1+1)
        for h in h_range:
            if (x1-h)>=0:
                i_range = np.arange(0,x1-h+1)
            else:
                break
            for i in i_range:
                if (y1-(m-i))>=0:
                    k_range = np.arange(0,y1-(m-i)+1)
                else:
                    break
                j = m-i
                if j>=0:
                    for k in k_range:
                        arguments = { "h":h, "i":i, "j":j, "k":k}
                        df = df.append(arguments, ignore_index=True)
        df["P"]= df.apply(lambda x: cal_P(x), axis=1)
        P_List.append(df.P.sum())
```

Output: `5 s ± 184 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Another way to do this:

```py
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["h","i","j","k"])
x1=10
y1=8
m=7
P_List = []
m_range = np.arange(0,m+1)

for m in m_range:
    h_range = np.arange(0,x1+1) 
    i_range = np.arange(0,x1+1)
    k_range = np.arange(0,y1+x1+2)
    j_range = np.arange(0,x1+m+1)

    data = np.array(np.meshgrid( h_range, i_range, k_range, j_range)).T.reshape(-1,4)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=[ "h","i","j","k"])

    i_cond = df.i<=(x1-df.h) #(x1-h)
    k_cond = df.k<=(y1-(m-df.i)) #(y1-(m-i))
    j_cond = df.j == (m-df.i)
    df = df.drop(df[~(i_cond&k_cond&j_cond)].index)
    df["P"]= df.apply(lambda x: cal_P(x), axis=1)
    P_List.append(df.P.sum())
```

Output: `306 ms ± 5.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Now the problem is that the value of x1, y1, and m is very large for my dataset. For the largest dataset, x1≈2000, y1≈1800, m≈500. So the 1st method is running forever, while the second method is running out of memory.

Is there anyway to do this faster without running out of memory? Or any other better way to calculate the above formula?

Edit:

P calculates the hypergeometric distribution for a value of m. I have updated the above code to reflect that.
[image: calculation of P]
where,
[image]
The 3-element trinomial function (a,b,c)! defined as:
[image]

For timing it `cal_P`is

```py
def cal_P(row):
    l = row.h+row.i+row.j+row.k
    return l
```

But the actual code to calculate the hypergeometric distribution is:

```py
from math import factorial as fact
def t_func(a,b,c):
    d=a-b-c
    if d>=0 and a>=0 and b>=0 and c>=0:
        result = fact(a)/(fact(b)*fact(c)*fact(d))     
    else:
        result = 0
    return result 

def hypergeom_XY(h, i, j, k, x1, x2, y1, y2, l):
    pmf = t_func(x1,h,i)*t_func(y1,j,k)*t_func(l-x1-y1,x2-h-j,y2-i-k)/t_func(l,x2,y2)
    return pmf

def cal_P(row):
   P = hypergeom_XY(row.h, row.i, row.j, row.k, x1, x2, y1, y2, l)
   return P
```

Comment: what is this formula for?  Is `P` for dimensional, depending on integer index?

Comment: and critically, what does `cal_P` look like?

Comment: I have added the the formulae for calculation of P. For timing it `cal_P` is just 
`return row.h+row.i+row.j+row.k`. But the actual cal_P calculates using the above formulae.

Comment: ah, missed your updates.  Ping me if posted solution is still too slow

Answer (score 1):

here is a cleaned up version of your first solution that I've verified returns the same results (with dummy definition for `cal_P`) that should be *relatively* performant while avoiding memory issues:

```
def cal_P(*x):
    return np.sum(np.array(x)**2)

%%timeit
x1=10
y1=8
m=7
P_List = []
m_range = np.arange(0, m+1)
for m in m_range:
    records = []
    for h in np.arange(0, x1+1):
        for i in np.arange(0, max(0, (x1-h+1))):
            j = m-i
            if j>=0:
                for k in np.arange(0, max(0, y1-j)+1):
                    arguments = { "h":h, "i":i, "j":j, "k":k}
                    records.append(arguments)
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    df["P"]= df.apply(cal_P, axis=1)
    P_List.append(df.P.sum())
```

P_List (both versions): `[5709, 9403, 11840, 13556, 14881, 15955, 16744, 17056]`.

- original (1st): `2.29 s ± 147 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- improved: `63.8 ms ± 219 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

I suspect `df.append` is what was slow.  In general, single row operations, esp. when modifying the df size, will be expensive.

The best way to speed up your code is to profile it (e.g. `cProfile`) to see what's slow - it's often something easy to change.  If you really need high performance, maybe iterate over one more index before invoking `meshgrid`.

Answer (score 1):

I converted your second code sample to generate *df* into the following function:

```
def f1(x1, y1, m):
    m_range = np.arange(0, m  + 1)
    h_range = np.arange(0, x1 + 1)
    i_range = np.arange(0, x1 + 1)
    k_range = np.arange(0, y1 + x1 + 2)
    j_range = np.arange(0, x1 + m  + 1)
    data = np.array(np.meshgrid(m_range, h_range, i_range,
        j_range, k_range)).T.reshape(-1, 5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['m', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'])
    i_cond = df.i <= (x1-df.h)
    k_cond = df.k <= (y1-(df.m-df.i))
    j_cond = df.j == (df.m-df.i)
    rowNo1 = df.index.size
    df = df.drop(df[~(i_cond & k_cond & j_cond)].index)
    rowNo2 = df.index.size
    return df, rowNo1, rowNo2
```

Note that it returns 3 results:

- *df* - the DataFrame itself,
- *rowNo1* - the number of rows before *drop*,
- *rowNo2* - the number of rows after *drop*.

I executed it on your data:

```
df, rN1, rN2 = f1(10, 8, 7)
print(f'{rN1}, {rN2}')
```

getting:

```
348480, 2010
```

Note that *rowNo1* is quite big.

Note also that inclusion of *j_range* in the *meshgrid* can be omitted and
then the row number is substantially smaller.

Column named *j* can be computed **after** *df* has been generated,
using *df.m - df.i* formula.

Then "unnecessary" rows can be eliminated, this time using *df.m >= df.i* formula.

So my proposition how to generate the source DataFrame is:

```
def f2(x1, y1, m):
    m_range = np.arange(0, m  + 1)
    h_range = np.arange(0, x1 + 1) 
    i_range = np.arange(0, x1 + 1)
    k_range = np.arange(0, y1 + x1 + 2)
    data = np.array(np.meshgrid(m_range, h_range, i_range,
        k_range)).T.reshape(-1, 4)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["m", "h", "i", "k"])
    df.insert(loc=3, column='j', value=df.m - df.i)
    i_cond = df.i <= (x1-df.h) 
    k_cond = df.k <= (y1-(df.m-df.i))
    j_cond = df.m >= df.i
    rowNo1 = df.index.size
    df = df.drop(df[~(i_cond & k_cond & j_cond)].index)
    rowNo2 = df.index.size
    return df, rowNo1, rowNo2
```

For comparison, I still compute row numbers before and after *drop*.

Then I executed:

```
df2, rN1, rN2 = f2(10, 8, 7)
print(f'{rN1}, {rN2}')
```

getting:

```
19360, 2010
```

Note that this time *rowNo1* is substantially smaller, so there is a better
chance that this function will not exhaust available memory on greater
values of *x1*, *y1* and *m*.

To check that both results (*df* and *df2*) are the same, I ran:

```
df.sort_values(['m', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ignore_index=True).equals(
    df2.sort_values(['m', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ignore_index=True))
```

getting *True*.

And the last important factor is the execution speed.
Using *%timeit* I got:

- *120 ms* for your code (*f1*),
- *7.69 ms* for my code (*f2*) - over 15 times faster.

Try my function, without returning both row numbers, on your real data.

Comment: Although numpy is more memory efficient than pandas, I think `data` is where the memory bottleneck will be.  A 4D `meshgrid` will kill you sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my first solution still leads to a *Memory exhausted*
exception. So I came up with other, "2-step" solution, more resistant
to memory exhaustion:

- First *h* and *i* columns are generated, based on *np.triu_indices*
  function.
- Then, for each group with particular *i* value, there are added
  *j* and *k* columns.

The code is as follows:

1. A function to generate *h* and *i* columns:

   ```
   def getHI(x1):
       ''' Generate "h" and "i" columns '''
       h, i = np.triu_indices(x1 + 1)
       return pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((h, x1 - i)).T, columns=['h', 'i'])
   ```
2. A function to add *j* and *k* columns, for the current group
   of rows (for some *i*):

   ```
   def addJK(grp, m, y1):
       ''' Add "j" and "k" columns to the current group '''
       i = grp.iloc[0,1]    # "i" column from the first row
       j = m - i
       if (y1 - j < 0) or (j < 0): return None
       kRng = y1 - j + 1
       res = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((np.tile(grp.values, (kRng, 1)),
           np.repeat(np.arange(kRng), grp.index.size)[:, np.newaxis])),
           columns=['h', 'i', 'k'])
       res.insert(2, 'j', j)  # Add "j" column
       return res
   ```
3. A new version of your *cal_P*:

   ```
   def cal_P2(hijk):
       return (hijk.h + hijk.i + hijk.j + hijk.k).astype(float).sum()
   ```

   The most important change is that the computation is **vectorized**,
   (the source object is a whole DataFrame, not individual row).
   This way you avoid *apply*, which operates much slower.

   Another change is that the result is of *float* type, because in
   your target version the result will be just *float*.

   Of course, your "true" *cal_P2* function must be also vectorized,
   otherwise the execution time will be **much** longer.
4. A function generating the sum of probabilities, for given *x1*, *y1*
   and *m* values:

   ```
   def getP(x1, y1, m):
       df_HI = getHI(x1)
       df_HIJK = df_HI.groupby('i', group_keys=False).apply(addJK, m=m, y1=y1)
       return cal_P2(df_HIJK)
   ```
5. A function generating a list of sum of probabilities, for each
   *m* from *0* to *mm*:

   ```
   def f2(x1, y1, mm):
       return [ getP(x1, y1, m) for m in range(mm + 1) ]
   ```

Note that because *m* is used inside the loop, I named the
top value of the loop as *mm*, so the code is more tidy.

I tested this function on your test data:

```
f2(10, 8, 7)
```

getting:

```
[891.0, 1691.0, 2380.0, 2940.0, 3355.0, 3611.0, 3696.0, 3600.0]
```

Compare it with the result generated by your code.
Compare also the execution times.

Then check the execution time for gradually increasing values of
*x1*, *y1* and *mm*.
I'm have no idea whether it is the best possible solution, but
at least you can treat it as one more option to try and compare
with other options you had so far.

An alternative to consider is to compute *getP* (the "individual"
probability, for particular *x1*, *y1* and *m* values), at least
during testing the execution time.